# Converting Date Format

Tags: php, date, format

I have script which scrap/fetch html table data from another website. The website date format is 26/8/2011, How I can change it to this format 2011-12-13??

```
function createRSSFile($tag,$value,$data)
 {
    # this will return the each element with tag.
    $tag=strtolower(str_replace(" ","_",$tag));
    $tag=strtolower(str_replace(":","",$tag));
    $tag=strtolower(str_replace("&","and",$tag));
    $returnITEM = "<".$tag.">".htmlspecialchars(str_replace(" 00:00:00","",$value))."</".$tag.">";
    return $returnITEM;
 } 

    function fetchData($jobid) {
       $html=file_get_contents('http://acbar.org/JobDetail.aspx?id='.$jobid);
       $html=str_replace("<td></td>", "",$html);
      $html=str_replace("<td style=\"font-size:8pt;font-weight:bold;\"></td>","<td style=\"font-size:8pt;font-weight:bold;\">Null</td>",$html);
      $html=str_replace("<td style=\"font-size:8pt;font-weight:bold;\" colspan=\"2\" ></td>","<td style=\"font-size:8pt;font-weight:bold;\" colspan=\"2\" >Null</td>",$html);

       $html=str_replace("&nbsp;", " ",$html);
       $html=str_replace("?", "<br>",$html);
       $html=str_replace("<br>", "_br_",$html);

       $dom = new DOMDocument;
       $dom->loadHTML( $html );
       //echo $dom->saveHTML();
       //exit;
       $rows = array();
       foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'tr' ) as $tr ) {
        $cells = array();
        foreach( $tr->getElementsByTagName( 'td' ) as $td ) {
            if(trim($td->nodeValue)!='')
              $cells[] = str_replace("_br_","<br>",trim($td->nodeValue));
        }
         if(sizeof($cells)>0)
           $rows[] = $cells;
       }
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just be a simple regex?

Answer (score 0):

Could always strtotime the date passed, then format it however you wish with date, like so...

```
$timeToModify = strtotime($passedTime);
$formattedTime = date("Y-m-D", $timeToModify);
```